# Can a tkinter window icon have a loading background in the program tray like when chrome downloads stuff

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

When a program like Chrome is downloading something, a green loading background appears behind the program icon on the windows program tray. Is it possible to do this with python with some kind of GUI package?
[Chrome program bar icon when downloading files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqFoJ.png)

Comment: Sure. If you want to animate it by having several icon files you can cycle through. Not sure if it will take an animated gif though.

Comment: The icon doesn't take up the entire taskbar area its given. Chrome is telling windows in some way to put a green backdrop behind the icon. When a program wants your attention it can even flash orange. I just want to know if there is a way to alert windows I am doing stuff but with python.